# How can we show that $\left\{x\in\mathbb R^d:d(x,\Lambda^c)>\varepsilon\right\}\subseteq\Lambda$, if $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ is a domain?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be connected and open. Now, let $\varepsilon>0$ and $$\Lambda_\varepsilon:=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^d:d(x,\Lambda^c)>\varepsilon\right\},$$ where $d$ denotes the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^d$. It's a simple question, but for the moment I don't see how we can show that $\Lambda_\varepsilon\subseteq\Lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \Lambda_{\epsilon}$. Suppose that on the contrary, $x \not \in \Lambda$. Therefore, $x \in \Lambda^c$ and in particular $d(x,  \Lambda^c) = 0$, which is absurd because we're supposing that $d(x,\Lambda^c)$ is positive.

Edit: note that here we're not using anything about $\Lambda$, in general if $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $\Lambda \subseteq X$ and $\Lambda_{\epsilon} = \{x \in X : d(x,\Lambda^c) > \varepsilon \}$, it holds that $\Lambda_{\epsilon} \subseteq \Lambda$.

Comment: Okay, it's late. Actually, that's not what I've intended to ask. Don't worry, I'll accept your answer. However, what I actually wanted to ask is how we can show that $$\left\{x+he_i:x\in\Lambda_\varepsilon\text{ and }h\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\right\}\subseteq\Lambda,$$ where $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector.

Comment: If $x \in \Lambda_\epsilon$ then for all $|h| < \epsilon$ and $y \in \Lambda^c$ we have (by the triangle inequality) $d(x, x + h e_i) + d(x + h e_i, y) \ge d(x, y) > \epsilon$ so $d(x + h e_i, y) > \epsilon - d(x, x + h e_i) = 0$. In particular $y$ can't be equal to $x + h e_i$ so $x + h e_i \not\in \Lambda^c$.